# CakePHP 3.x Multiple login methods

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to figure out how I could go about automatically logging in a user by clicking an e-mail URL which has the user's ID attached to it.

Currently, the only way to log in is to enter the username and the password in the log in screen.

Basically I just need to know if there's a way for me to use $this->Auth->identify() with the user ID, instead of the username and password.

Below is the code I use to identify the user:

```
if($this->request->is('post')){
        $user = $this->Auth->identify();
        if($user){
            $this->Auth->setUser($user);
            return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'dashboards']);
        }else{
            $this->Flash->error(__('Incorrect login!'));
            $this->redirect(['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login']);
        }

    }
```

Comment: You want to validate user with only User Id ?

Comment: I want to validate the user both through the conventional log in(username, password), as well as using the link attached in the e-mail(user ID).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so what I did was to create an entirely new function in the controller and had used a form in the e-mail so that the user ID is sent through POST. This prevents other users to manually enter the URL and append a random number to gain access in to other accounts.

First I had to allow the function to proceed without going through authentication.

```
public function beforeFilter(Event $event){
    $this->Auth->allow('emailLogin');
}

public function emailLogin(){
    $this->autoRender = false;
    $user_id = $_POST['user_id'];

    if($this->Auth->user()){
        $this->Flash->error(__('You are already logged in!'));
        return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'dashboards']);
    }
```

And here is the function I used:

```
    if($user_id == null){
        $this->Flash->error(__('Access has been denied!'));
        $this->redirect(['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login']);
    }else{
        $user = $this->Users->get($user_id);
        if($user){
            $this->Auth->setUser($user->toArray());
            $this->Flash->success('E-mail log in successful.');
            $this->redirect(['controller' => 'dashboards']);
        }else{
            $this->Flash->error(__('Access has been denied!'));
            $this->redirect(['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login']);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see how you have any security on this. Seems that anyone could put any user id on the end of a manually-constructed URL and be logged in as that person.

Comment: Appending a user ID at the end of the URL actually declines user access as I have sent the user ID through a form instead.

Comment: Ah, I missed that. Still, what prevents someone from making their own form that submits an arbitrary user id? Or editing the email that you send them to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution,

first allow login method to access with out login,

```
 class UsersController extends AppController
    {
        public function initialize(){
                parent::initialize();
                $this->Auth->allow('login');
            }



public function login($id = null)   // here login method can accept parameter you pass with URL from email
    {
        if($id){ // If it is link with User Id
            $this->loadModel('Users');
            $user = $this->Users->get($id);  // get user data
            if($user){
              $this->Auth->setUser($user);    // set user
              $this->Flash->success(__('Welcome'));
              return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
            }else{
              $this->Flash->error(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
            }
        }
        if ($this->request->is('post')) { // if use login page with username &password
            $user = $this->Auth->identify(); // use Auth method to identify
            if ($user) {
                $this->Auth->setUser($user);
                $this->Flash->success(__('Welcome'));
                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
            }else{
                $this->Flash->error(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
            }
        }
    }

    }
```

This will work for you

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work for me. Upon following the link, expecting it to automatically log me in, it just redirected me to the log in page and is asking for a username and password.

Comment: did you put $this->Auth->allow('login'); to initialize()  ?

Comment: I did. I also tried putting $this->Auth->allow('login') inside beforeFilter() but still nothing.

Comment: are you passing user Id with url ? because without that it won't work.

Comment: Yes, the user ID is being passed as a parameter for the function.

Comment: and from routing your url must allow to pass parameter.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142041/discussion-between-mr-j-and-marc-bien-go).